# [SVN]: How to backup repository?

Tags: svn

If the repository is contained in a folder, is it sufficient to take the backup of this folder instead of typing the commands to create a dump?

Comment: what is wrong with dump? It supports deltas and increments which could be really useful if you have a big repository and regular backups

Comment: @hapalibashi: I tried using dump, but my PC started beeping continuously and it started showing machine language on the screen.

Comment: @Rohit: It sounds like dump is working properly. Except, it dumps to standard output; you need to redirect that output into a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in great detail in the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup):

> As far as full backups go, the naïve approach might seem like a sane one, but unless you temporarily disable all other access to your repository, simply doing a recursive directory copy runs the risk of generating a faulty backup. In the case of Berkeley DB, the documentation describes a certain order in which database files can be copied that will guarantee a valid backup copy. A similar ordering exists for FSFS data. But you don't have to implement these algorithms yourself, because the Subversion development team has already done so. The *svnadmin hotcopy* command takes care of the minutia involved in making a hot backup of your repository. And its invocation is as trivial as the Unix *cp* or Windows *copy* operations:
>
> ```
> $ svnadmin hotcopy /var/svn/repos /var/svn/repos-backup
> ```
>
> The resultant backup is a fully functional Subversion repository, able to be dropped in as a replacement for your live repository should something go horribly wrong.
>
> ...
>
> Additional tooling around this command is available, too. The *tools/backup/* directory of the Subversion source distribution holds the *hot-backup.py* script. This script adds a bit of backup management atop *svnadmin hotcopy,* allowing you to keep only the most recent configured number of backups of each repository. It will automatically manage the names of the backed-up repository directories to avoid collisions with previous backups and will “rotate off” older backups, deleting them so that only the most recent ones remain. Even if you also have an incremental backup, you might want to run this program on a regular basis. For example, you might consider using *hot-backup.py* from a program scheduler (such as *cron* on Unix systems), which can cause it to run nightly (or at whatever granularity of time you deem safe).

Comment: +1 was about to type in the same answer. :-)

Comment: Meh, this one was mostly copy and paste, not typing :-) But for most things you can or have to do with Subversion the Subversion Book has the answer so it was a pretty trivial research :-)

Comment: +1 do an svnadmin hotcopy and take a backup of the hotcopy output.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this [page](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_backup_and_restore).

If you only want to backup a checkout you can archive it like a normal folder, the svn configs are stored in the `.svn` folders located in every folders of your repository.

*(The question should be moved on superuser)*

Comment: My repositories are in my localhost.

Comment: Then it will look exactly the same.

Comment: As others have said, directly backing up a repository from the filesystem is generally considered a bad habbit. If a commit is taking place when your backup script fires, you're going to find yourself in a world of pain if you need to restore.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot backup a repository folder without locking the repository. See [this chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup) of the SVN book for more information regarding backups.

A dump is one way to do a backup. You could also make a hotcopy:

```
svnadmin hotcopy /var/svn/repos /var/svn/repos-backup
```

Or you can use `svnsync` to constantly keep around an up-to-date copy of your repository. If you don't have a powerful SVN server, this also has the advantage that it prevents bringing the server down to its knees for backups.

Comment: What is the difference between a dump and a hotcopy?

Comment: The document I linked to says regarding hotcopy: "The resultant backup is a fully functional Subversion repository, able to be dropped in as a replacement for your live repository should something go horribly wrong." A dump doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that no user will commit anything while you are copying the repository folder, then it's safe.

Otherwise, using the hotcopy or dump command is recommended.